# how to handle delete by illegal address

Tags: c++, exception, new-operator

Suppose we have a situation like this. Suppose instead of "p = &global;" we called some function(written by someone which invalidate our pointer). How to handle this problem? How to protect code from crashes? I know about and use boost smart pointers. But what to do if we have this situation.

```
struct Test
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

Test global;

int main()
{
    Test *p = new Test;

    p->a = 1;
    p->b = 2;
    p->c = 3;

    p = &global;

    delete p;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My spontaneous answer would be not to do things this way. There may be patterns to work around it though.

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place?!

Comment: A man walks into the doctor's office and says, "Doctor, it hurts when I do this!"  The doctor looks at him and says, "Then don't do that!"

Comment: Davit, don't forget to accept answers to your previous questions that solved the problem by using the check-mark - see the FAQ for details.

Comment: This is a runtime error Wadih M.

Comment: @Wadih: *a)* The heap-allocated `Test` is leaked and *b)* trying to delete stack-allocated objects invokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code below to find out if a pointer points to a stack area or heap area:

```
bool IsMemoryOnStack( void* p )
{
    void* dwStackTop = 0;
    void* dwStackLowCurrent = 0;
    __asm  {
        mov EAX, FS:[4]
        mov dwStackTop, eax
            mov EAX, FS:[8]
            mov dwStackLowCurrent, eax
    }

    return ( p<= dwStackTop && p>= dwStackLowCurrent );
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You handle it by fixing the bug and recompiling your program.  Anything else makes no sense.

Answer (score 9):

You can't and you shouldn't try to deal with this situation other then not letting it occur in the first place.
There are some basic rules in C++ that simply have to be obeyed.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing.  If you do this, then you get what you get.  Don't do this.

Once you reassign `p`, you leak the `Test` object that `p` originally pointed at.  You've now lost that memory for the duration of this app's runtime.  Then when you delete a non-heap object, you're running into undefined behaviour and anything at all can happen (usually the runtime library will crash trying to delete non-heap memory - but you have no guarantees).  There's absolutely nothing reliable that you can do once you've tried to delete non-heap memory.

You've already mentioned smart pointers, which is part of the solution.  The other part is just being careful.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there's nothing you can do. The C++ compiler can't tell from your code whether or not you might delete a pointer in the future, so you have to be sure to manage them correctly in your code. This means that if you put the address of a non-heap-allocated item into a pointer, it's your responsibility nto to delete that pointer.

In short, C++ can't protect you from every possible mistake you can write.

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap the assignment and delete statements:

```
 delete p;
 p = &global;
```

BUT I would suggest never using the same variable to point at data that requires an explicit free and data that does not. Pick one or the other for each variable, so you can either always delete the memory before reassigning it or never delete it. If you try to keep track of how you're pointers got set, you'll wind up spending all your time whining about how C++ provides no memory management and forces you to write unmaintainable code.

Comment: Hi John, please try understand problem. I wrote p = &global for show runtime error. The problem is that during work you can use some lib/function written by someone and that usage can invalidate your pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The primary way to avoid this is to simply avoid using `new` or `delete` under any but the most tightly controlled circumstances.

Using `new` inside of `main` is particularly suspect -- *the* reason to use `new` in C++ is when you need to create an object that needs to outlive the scope in which it's being created (e.g., when you reach the end of that function, it must *not* be destroyed). In the case of `main`, the *only* reason to do what would be if you were allocating something in `main` that would *not* be deleted in main, but used by some the destructor of some global object as it ran after you returned from `main` (which is rarely done and even more rarely a good idea).

Most uses of `new` should be in the ctor of an object, and most uses of `delete` should be in the dtor of an object. If you have something like a collection, it can also make sense to use `new` and/or `delete` in some other member function(s) that handle(s) things like re-sizing the collection.

Other than that, there are entity objects that generally aren't ever assigned or copied. For example, consider a call routing system, where you create a "call" object when somebody dials their phone, and you destroy the object when they hang up. In nearly every such case, you have a global collection (or more than one) that holds pointers to these objects, so as soon as you create the object, its address goes into the (correct) global collection. Interesting point: nearly all code that I've seen where this pattern made sense did *not* have any external code that destroyed the object -- rather, the object itself was responsible for removing itself from the global connection, and using the (much argued-about) `delete this;` to destroy itself when the real-world connection (or whatever) it was attached to ended.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to overload `delete`.  In theory you could have your overloaded `delete` refuse to do anything unless the address is valid.  But how do you know if it's valid?  The best you can say is "this wasn't allocated with `new`," but you'll probably have to overload `new` to do that.

For the record, the standard `new` and `delete` crash in this case because `delete` determines the address didn't come from `new` and assumes the worst.  Assuming the worst is probably the best thing to do in that situation, though; at least it beats assuming the best.

So I'll second the advice to not protect against this in code, and simply don't do that.

Comment: unfortunately, there's no guarantee of a crash.